# How to prepare a ginger lime drink mixer?

Tags: drinks, syrup, ginger, lime, infusion

I am trying to prepare a ginger lime (basil) drink mixer.  It will be mixed with Whiskey the day of the event.

Is it better to prepare a limeade via steeping or a syrup via cooking?  Will the acid in the limes dissolve the ginger and basil over time (i.e. would it ruin the appearance / would I be able to filter them out)?

Will either of them last two weeks until the event?  I plan to keep them in a sealed jar in the fridge.  Does anyone have any advice on proportions?

Comment: Just a heads up: recipe requests aren't really on topic here. Your question asks for plenty besides a recipe/proportions, so I don't want to vote to close it, but it's best to focus on the "can I make this ahead" part, rather than the proportions; there are plenty of cocktail recipe sites out there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you will have a bartender or not but as a former Bartender here is how I would approach it.  You'll have to experiment in advance for the flavor you are trying to achieve.  Since everything you are working with is sharp I would make a ginger simple syrup. 1/2 water 1/2 household sugar and probably about a tablespoon of fresh grated ginger. Heat until all the sugar is melted and then let it steep until you are are happy with the ginger flavor. bottle it and keep it in the refrigerator.

I would start with:

- 1/4 oz ginger syrup
- 1 oz Whiskey
- splash of fresh lime juice
- garnish with a bruised basil leaf.

and adjust the measures until you get what you are looking for.

If you are looking for something sparkling try:

- 1 oz whiskey
- 2 oz ginger ale
- 1/2 oz Rose's Lime juice

with the same garnish.

Comment: How much water/sugar syrup to the tbls of ginger?

Comment: start with a cup until you have what you want then proportion up to the quantity you need

Comment: Please try to format your answers clearly. There are buttons above the text entry box to help you out with it, and you can see a preview of your answer below. I've edited this one for you; to see the difference you can click on the edit timestamp by my name above.

Comment: You also haven't really answered what may be the more important part of the question: is it possible to mix it up with the basil ahead of time?

Answer (score 1):

Make a liquor; use some whiskey or vodka and add the other ingredients into a well sealed container and freeze for a few weeks. They will dissolve into the alcohol

You will probably need to use a very fine strainer to clarify it